# Downgrade SQL CE from 4 to 3.5?

Tags: sql-server-ce, vistadb

Does anyone know if it's possible to downgrade an existing SQL CE 4 database to 3.5? The reason I ask is because I'm looking to migrate from SQL CE to VistaDB...and VistaDB's data migration wizard only takes SQL CE 3.5 db's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just found an answer to my own question. Using Data Port Console, you can do an export of an existing SQL CE 4 database to a 3.5 db. Then using Vista DB's Data Migration Wizard, you can import that 3.5 version of the db. It seems to have worked amazingly well and took about 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use my scripting tools to export the 4.0 file to a sql script, and create the 3.5 file from the script, as I describe here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded it in 20 sec using [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/104781) ,Thanks ErikEJ ,Thumb up.